# SLURM script to run indefinitely to avoid session timeout

Tags: ssh, terminal, hpc, slurm

Background:

- I need to remote access a HPC across the country (place is closed for public, I am interning for the summer)
- Once I accomplish this, I load a script, for this purpose let's call it jupyter.sh
- There are several nodes in this HPC, and  every time I run the .sh script, I get assigned to one, say N123
- From Jupyter notebook on browser, I have to run actual code/ calculations/ simulations using python. The data I'm working with takes about 2 hours to run completely so that I can then process it and do my job
- Very often, I would get disconnected from that node N123 because "user doesn't have an active job running", even though my jupyter notebook is still running / I'm working on it
- This results in me having to run that .sh script again, meaning I will get a different node, say N456 (then the ssh command line for jupyter has to be entered again, this time with the different node number)
- Jupyter will disconnect from host, and this forces me to restart kernel and run the entire code again, costing me that 1 hour and something it takes to run the python code.
  (Can't get into too many details since I don't know what I am allowed to share without getting in trouble)

My question is,
Is there a way that i can run an sh script with say, an infinite loop, so that the node sees it as an active job running and it doesn't kick me out for "inactivity" ?
I have tried running different notebooks that take about 10 minutes total to run, but this doesn't seem to be enough to be considered an active job (and I am not sure if it even counts)

My experience with slurm, terminal and ssh processes is very limited, so if this is a silly question, please forgive.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --job-name=pytorch
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user== NO NEED TO SEE THIS
#SBATCH --partition=shared-gpu
#SBATCH --qos=long
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=2G
#SBATCH --time=04:00:00
export PORT=8892
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:$PORT)
# Config stuff
module purge
module load anaconda/Anaconda3
module load cuda/10.2
source activate NO NEED FOR THIS
# Print stuff
echo Working directory is $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
echo Running on host `hostname`
echo Time is `date`
### Define number of processors
echo This job has allocated $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES nodes
# Tell me which nodes it is run on
echo " "
echo This jobs runs on the following processors:
echo $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
echo " "
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=$PORT
echo Time is `date
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=jupyter               # Job name
#SBATCH --nodes=1                        # Run all processes on a single node.  
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                       # Run a single task        
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1                # Number of CPU cores per task (multithreaded tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=2G                         # Job memory request. If you do not ask for enough your program will be killed.
#SBATCH --time=04:00:00                  # Time limit hrs:min:sec. If your program is still running when this timer ends it will be killed.

srun jupyter.sh
```

work? You write this up in a text editor, save it as .slurm, then run it using
`sbatch jobname.slurm`
Salloc might also be a good way to go about this.

Comment: The salloc line is part of the main sh file I am running, and it reads: salloc -p shared gpu
Is this what you mean?
I am going to write and run that script, and hope it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you need a GPU, you need to add the line #SBATCH --gres=gpu:N where N is how many GPUs you need. You should probably also add #SBATCH -p shared gpu to here as well. Better bet might be editing the salloc line, but it should not have a deadline by default.

Comment: I also just realized you are providing the lines I could add to my sh file already. 
Which basically it gives it a time length to run. I may have to try this and see if it helps, since I just ran my first sbatch file for the day and before waiting the two hours it takes to run, might as well kill it now and run the sh file with those lines and then move to jupyter as normal

Comment: Added the actual code plus the lines you provided. I'm wondering if it will wait 4 hours to then let me launch jupyter from browser...

Comment: That 4 hours is a time limit- its basically telling the scheduler that "I want x amount of resources but Ill only need it for a max of four hours, I promise." If it goes over 4 hours, It'll kill the job. Im hoping adding the time limit will prevent it from killing it before then- Im not sure what restrictions your administrators have on the system, I dont think mine kills jobs just for being empty like this. Try adding srun on the Jupyter line, like srun jupyter --no-browser etc.

Comment: does this help? https://nero-docs.stanford.edu/jupyter-slurm.html

Comment: National lab computers are a pain to access to.